# Online introduction to Lattice Theory?

Tags: reference-request, lattice-theory, online-resources

Apart from J. B Nation's [Notes on Lattice Theory](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Ejb/), is there any other (mostly introductory) material on Lattices available online?

**NB**: The last update of Nation's notes was 2017, as of Feb 2023.

Comment: See also: [Good lattice theory books?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14341#48739)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something brief to begin with see the [notes](http://www.rasmusen.org/GI/lattice.theory.notes.txt) by Eric Rasmusen, the introductions to lattice theory by [Zukowski](http://mizar.org/JFM/pdf/lattices.pdf) and [Wang](http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/%7Ewang/research/coin/lattice.pdf)

[An essay on history](http://www.ams.org/notices/199711/comm-rota.pdf), somewhat from a personal view, by Giancarlo Rota is also nice.

Answer (score 6):

There is Burris and Sankappanavar's free book [A Course in Universal Algebra](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is also pretty good

http://boole.stanford.edu/cs353/handouts/book1.pdf

short and sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but who knows this might be useful to someone. A video lecture on Lattices:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPtGlrb_sXg

Answer (score 0):

- Another intro: "[An Introduction to Order Theory](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=111242)" by Zack French and James B. Hart, AMS Open Math Notes, 2020. It covers: Modular and Distributive Lattices / Relatively Complemented Lattices / Adjunctions and Heyting Lattices / Closure Operators and Compact Generation / Irreducible Elements in Lattices.
- Coverage by another textbook about universal algebra: "[An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/245/)" by George M. Bergman, 2015. It was published by Springer, but the author also provides a pdf, last updated in 2020.